# phpMyAdmin: how to edit BINARY or VARBINARY as text?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

I have recently converted some CHAR and VARCHAR columns in my database to BINARY and VARBINARY because I wanted searches to be case-sensitive by default and speed up my queries (which has worked well so far).

What I didn't realize at the time is that, while phpMyAdmin still **shows** these values as texts in the SELECT view, it no longer allows me to **edit** them as text.

When I go to the "edit" pages, the values are now displayed numerically. There is a "function" dropdown which seems to be offering character conversions, but selections there don't refresh the view or reveal the text values.

So, is there any other way to edit BINARY and VARBINARY contents as text in the UI?

(I am on a shared host and can't change the global configuration btw.)

Comment: *I have recently converted some CHAR and VARCHAR columns in my database to BINARY and VARBINARY because I wanted searches to be case-sensitive by default* Change column collation to case-sensitive or binary would be enough...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccc26821c83aac6dc6a75df26dec7e5d

Comment: Thanks Akina, that's a very good point! I will revert / update the schema accordingly.